# Are network protocols on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23332279/1864610) as off-topic. It's about network discovery protocols, and at first I voted to close because it appeared to be looking for some online tutorial. The OP has objected, so I looked again. Disregarding whether my original assessment was correct, the question is looking for a general discussion on discovery protocols, rather than a specific implementation question. This doesn't look to me like a programming question suitable for Stack Overflow.

The OP is still questioning my assessment, so, is this specific question on-topic or off-topic on Stack Overflow? And more generally, could questions about the general nature of any particular network protocol be considered as on-topic?

Comment: By the way, the poster of [How does Discovery service work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23332279/456814) also links to [Approaches to implement Service discovery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17314368/456814), which judging from the title alone, ***also*** looks like it could be too broad, though I haven't taken the time to take a closer look.

Comment: @Cupcake I took a closer look. I'd close it as 'opinion-based', but 'too broad' would fit too.

Answer (score 20):

## Are network protocols on-topic on Stack Overflow?

I would argue **Yes,** but only as long as they're related to ***a specific
programming problem.***

If you're just trying to figure out how to administer a server or IT
infrastructure, then I would say **No.** That's [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)'s realm.

However, the specific question has many other issues (so don't just kick it over
to Server Fault). Let's take a look.

## Question Issues

### Title (and by proxy, the problem) is too broad

> How does Discovery service work?

As stated, you could write an entire blog post or two (or a book?) on the
question "How does Discovery service work?" The question could be improved by
asking about ***a particular, specific aspect or problem about the protocol.***

### Asking for off-site resources

> **How can I learn more about how Discovery service works?**
>
> Can someone explain it in detail? Tried finding resources online but I am
> afraid I may not be googling it well enough as I can't find sufficient depth
> in the current results. Links would also be appreciated.

Asking for an off-site learning resource ("Links...appreciated"). Also a close
reason.

## I Googled "Discovery Protocol", and This is What I Found

[Google "discovery protocol"](https://www.google.com/search?q=discovery+protocol), and look at what you get. This isn't
really a close reason, but it could possibly be a reason to downvote (see the Research
section below). If the poster had actually said "I googled these", and listed
the links, and gave a reason why none of the links answered his question, then
the question would have been ***much more useful, to everyone involved:***

1. [Simple Service Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol).
2. [Link Layer Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol).
3. [Service discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery).
4. [Neighbor Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol).
5. [Cisco Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol).
6. [Nortel Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nortel_Discovery_Protocol).
7. [Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSDP).
8. [Network Service Discovery](http://www.w3.org/TR/discovery-api/)/
9. [Configuring Cisco Discovery Protocol on Cisco Routers and Switches Running Cisco IOS](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/network-management/discovery-protocol-cdp/43485-cdponios43485.html).
10. [LLDP-MED and Cisco Discovery Protocol](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk652/tk701/technologies_white_paper0900aecd804cd46d.html).

***Those were all on the first page*** of search results.

### Research That the Original Poster *Did* Do

The original poster states (emphasis mine)

> Tried finding resources online but I am afraid I may not be googling it well
> enough as **I can't find sufficient depth in the current results.** Links
> would also be appreciated.

At the bottom of the first link you'll find a [References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol#References) section. The
first item in that list is [an implementation draft for the Simple Service
Discovery Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cai-ssdp-v1-03). It may be outdated, ***but at least it's a start in
the right search direction.*** Repeat for every other reference link in every
other Wikipedia article.

The original poster also states:

> Found some relevant info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314368/approaches-to-implement-service-discovery) on stackoverflow, but isn't really
> explaining much.

So at least ***some research*** was done, though "isn't really explaining much"
doesn't really explain what was in the linked resource, and why it wasn't
helpful. **So upvote/downvote/no-vote, your call.**

## Vote to Close, but for Which Reason?

This post can fit the following close reasons:

1. Too broad.
2. Asks for off-site resource recommendations.
3. Doesn't appear to be a programming problem.

The original poster didn't really state ***why*** he wants to learn about this
protocol, so we can't exactly close as #3. I would say that the fact that the
question is so broad weighs more heavily as a close reason than the fact that
it's asking for off-site resources.

My verdict: **Too broad. Vote to close.**

Comment: What about closing it as *Off-Topic: questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration*, instead of *Too broad*?

Comment: @JWLim One problem with that is the 'professional' requirement on that site. I'm never quite sure whether some of these questions meet that criterion.

Comment: @JWLim updated answer. The original poster of that question didn't state ***why*** he wanted to learn about the protocol...maybe it ***does involve a programming problem.*** But we don't know with the information given. Therefore, can't make the call either way.

Comment: Some are narrowing the definition of "problem" to only troubleshooting programming issues. There are "problem" statements dealing with optimization where there isn't a problem in the sense of something is wrong, but they are trying to make something better. A discussion of what algorithms would be best for a given scenario is also a programming problem, but may not involve actual code in question/answer as most algorithms are code agnostic.   I agree that it is too broad, but that leaves the door open for improvement. Saying it is not a programming problem shuts that door prematurely IMO.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to be part of the conversation as I am the original poster of the question. I've been downvoted enough to go below 50 points so can't comment on this site, hence writing in as a reply. To clarify:

1) Too broad. - Yes, I am trying to learn how the service works for my education.

2) Asks for off-site resource recommendations - Yes, a book, reference would help as I cannot find it easily yet

3) Doesn't appear to be a programming problem.- Yes, I don't have a particular programming problem to solve. My problem is figuring out how to implement it.

So can you confirm it is indeed not for Stack Overflow? According to the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page

Don't ask about...

1. Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
2. Product or service recommendations or comparisons
3. Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
4. Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Thought I could proceed based on this set of criteria.

So can someone clarify if my interpretation is wrong, and also if Server Fault is the right place for such questions? (If not, is there one in our Stack Exchange system?)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't just post to [sf] straight away, or you'll probably be downvoted and closed there too. Your question needs some work. It might be a possibility that it's not a good fit for any current Stack Exchange site, in which case you'll be better off asking in some kind of forum or something.

Comment: This might actually be worth asking a different question about on Meta, since the original question was about whether network protocols are on-topic for [main]. Let me think...

Comment: I'm asking the question for you, give me a few minutes...

Comment: Alright, done. Please see [I want to learn how to implement a discovery protocol, is this appropriate for SO or SF? If not, how can I make it a good fit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252645/456814).