# Is it okay to ask "how does * work" questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, asking-questions, scope

Is it okay to ask questions about the functioning of certain software/network systems?

For example: How does a merchant website receive payments from users and distribute them across other users as payments using the PayPal API.

Expected answer: directions about the relevant parts of the documentation, examples of integration scripts, etc.

Comment: Is that exactly the question that you would have asked? Because if it is, I would say that it's too broad, and maybe that it even lacks research effort. But that's just my own opinion on it so far.

Comment: No I haven't asked it and it's just an example. I'm referring to the general question style that it represents: as you said, a quite broad but programming-related question aimed at getting an explanation and introduction to the subject

Comment: Related: [I want to learn how to implement a discovery protocol, is this appropriate for SO or SF? If not, how can I make it a good fit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252645/456814). Not that it answers this question at all, it's just another example with opinions on a question like the one that you gave as an example.

Comment: Most general "how does x work" questions are indeed going to be off topic. More specific ones might work.

Comment: It sounds like a fantastic question.  Just paste in some relevant code, to satisfy the "include code!" social norm on SO.

Answer (score 8):

Not really.

Here's why:  **we don't know what your level of expertise is.**

"How does this work," without any context whatsoever, is the same question as "why doesn't my code work," and we routinely close those as well.  We close "why doesn't my code work" questions as "Insufficient Information to Diagnose Problem."  We close "How does this code work" as Too Broad.

Now, if you provide some code, explain that you've traced it out like so, explain your current understanding, but you don't understand how some specific part works, then at least we have some idea of your level of knowledge, and can respond appropriately.

Comment: seems to me like Documentation expansion proposal would be a good fit here

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If it's too general such as "How does merchant website receive payments" then most likely no because it's too broad. On the other hand "How does javascript event loop work" is known to be on topic and considered a good question because it clarifies a common misunderstanding of the nature of javascript.

"How does" is too broad a phrase to be considered a category. Instead look at how narrow or broad the level of detail is.

So how would someone know if his "how does" question is too broad? In my experience, one hint is to look at the subject:

- If it's "How does *a feature* work" it's generally too broad
- If it's "How does *a technology* work" it's probably acceptable

The difference is, features are user-visible program features such as "file sharing" and "accepting payment". Technology are specific technical issues such as "tcp handshake" and "http POST request".