# Are specification implementation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to find a place to ask a question about implementing an IETF standard, and wondered if such questions were on-topic on this site?

The quesiton is not specifically about *programming* the implementation, but rather about which way a specification should be implemented (my understanding of the spec differs from what I'm seeing in the wild, which may mean I'm understanding it wrong, it may be that one or two places implement it wrong, or it may be that enough people implemented it wrong so everyone else does for compatibility and the spec is just ignored).

I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252645/can-a-question-about-implementing-a-protocol-be-made-a-good-fit) question, and of course the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), but am still unsure if this sort of quesiton is a good fit. I couldn't find any similar example questions that set any sort of precedence either. I thought it might fit under the last item in the help center article about what is on topic:

> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

### Example question

> I have written an XMPP client and am trying to make it compatible with International Domain Names as specified in [RFC 6122](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6122.html). In the RFC it states: "Although XMPP applications do not communicate the output of the ToASCII operation (called an "ACE label") over the wire, it MUST be possible to apply that operation without failing to each internationalized label." However, with the servers I've tested, sending a Unicode name in the "to" field of an XMPP stanza causes them to immediately return an error. What is the correct way to implement...

**EDIT:** I've gone ahead and posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891594/implementation-of-idns-in-jids-as-specified-in-rfc-6122). Thanks for your help and comments.

Comment: sounds a little opinion based?

Comment: I don't think so; I've added a quick version of the question as an example to illustrate. It's about a spec, so there should definitely be one correct answer (eg. "The spec means this... people actually do this... this is how it should be done to make sure things work properly")

Comment: @SamWhited "how do I (achieve these requirements)..." sounds a bit less opinion based

Comment: That can only fly if you add an MCVE code and the testresult with one or two servers and then you ask the question: the specs say.... Why doesn't this work?

Comment: That may be a better way of phrasing it; the code itself seems a bit irrelavant either way though (which is why I was hesitant about posting it on SO).

Comment: In this case you don't need the XMPP client code, if you provide the message actually sent to the servers (probably including hex dump of the "to" field and contents specifically).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think these types of questions can be on topic. You already found the most relevant part of the help center. Let me expand around the quote some more, and add emphasis:

> We feel **the best** Stack Overflow questions **have** a bit of **source code** in them, **but** if your question generally covers
>   ...
>   a **practical**, **answerable** problem that is unique to **software development**
>   ...
>   then **you’re in the right place** to ask your question!

This clearly specifies that questions without source code can be on topic. As far a I can tell, questions about standards relevant to software development meet all these criteria. They are obviously about software development. They can certainly be practical. And if you ask them clearly and precisely enough, they can be answerable.

Unfortunately I don't understand the technology behind your specific example, so I can't give you feedback on it. But from my superficial impression, it looks like it could be an on topic question for SO.

Beyond just interpreting the exact wording in the help center, it's just as important to keep the overall spirit in mind. When you're about to ask a question, some of the key criteria to keep in mind are:

- Can it be answered within the format of this site?
- Can possible answers be evaluated based on technical criteria?
- Will the question and possible answers provide useful content to the target audience of this site?

If you look at your own question, and can answer with a clear *YES* to all of them, I say: Go for it! I'm sure you already covered all the general basics, like checking that the question is not a duplicate.