# Is it on-topic to ask a question about protocol irrespective of its programming usage?

Tags: discussion, scope

Let us say I have developed a TCP server using C#.NET and facing some issues. While debugging I come across CLOSE_WAIT status and could not understand what/why is that.

So my question is "What is CLOSE_WAIT status in TCPIP?" tagged with [tcp-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp-ip).  No any other tag mentioned. Question body also does not contain any more information than title itself. No any programming language, tool-kit etc mentioned either.

I mentioned TCPIP just for an example. **My question is general for any *well known public* protocol** that **can be implemented using some programming language**. A protocol for which multiple toolkits are available and/or have in-build support in programming language. So [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252627/5779732) is good reference but not exact as it only talks about network protocol.

Please understand that my question is about being "on-topic". If someone down vote the question (because its body is very short lets say) then that is different issue with question. I am not asking about it here. I am also not talking about other close reasons like "too-broad".

Will such a question be closed due to any one reasons under "Closing>Off-Topic" such as below:

- general computing hardware and software
- professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration
- recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource (**Note: Question body or title does not explicitly ask for any resource**)
- debugging help
- a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error
- question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

## Example 2 (as asked in comment):

I have developed a Storage SCU using C#.NET and having problem while communicating with one specific equipment. The reason is "invalid image type". So my question is "What is the use of Image Type tag in DICOM?" tagged with [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom). Rest of the things are similar to earlier example; I do not repeat those here.

## Example 3:

I have developed a MLLP Client using C#.NET and having problem while communicating with one MLLP Server. Through debugging, I found that Server is sending "Enhanced Mode Acknowledgement" and my application only support "Original Mode Acknowledgement". So my question is "What is Enhanced Mode Acknowledgement in MLLP?" tagged with [mllp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mllp).

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: It might not be a network protocol. It might be other protocol that can be implemented using programming language.

Comment: Can you add more examples to your question, to better describe these other hypothetical protocols?

Comment: Yeah, TCP CLOSE_WAIT is a bad example and such a question would surely be closed as 'Too broad', 'Unclear' or 'tutorial request', (real reason - not Googling or reading the RFC).

Comment: I can certainly imagine some protocol questions that may be on-topic.  Maybe there is code and/or a state-table, and some desired behaviour that is troublesome to implement or testing reveals some obscure operation.  Maybe..

Comment: @MartinJames: IMHO down vote should be the way to express "not Googling or reading the RFC". There is no tutorial request in question title or body (question updated). As I mentioned in my question, I only want to know about being on-topic; not about other reasons mentioned by you.

Comment: I think all 3 examples have the same issue as the first TCP example, which Martin James points out. They’ll all be closed as “unclear what you’re asking”, as that reason is now used as a catch-all for “unclear why you’re asking”, aka “your question needs to demonstrate (a) a minimal understanding of the material you’re asking about and (b) that you’ve done the basic legwork for yourself and that’s evident in the Q”. We used to have specific close reasons for that but SO decided to merge them with “unclear”.

Comment: 'There is no tutorial request in question' yes, youre right - it's implied.  Thanks for the examples, though.  I will wait to see what those familiar with the protocols have to say:)

Comment: That said, the way to rescue all 3 Qs is the same and it also straightforward: show us what you found in the manual/RFP/googling for this topic, and why it wasn’t sufficient to solve he problem. Don’t ask someone else to read the manual or google search for you. Do the basic legwork yourself, show your readers you did in the body of your Q itself, and tell them precisely where you’re hung up.

Comment: IMO they are all on topic and should be closed as too broad.

Comment: @DanBron: IMHO question will be very clear to experienced user in that protocol. He will clearly understand what OP is asking and why. If someone is not experienced in particular technology, I am not sure how he should treat that post.

Comment: @Oleg: Example 2 and 3 can be very well answered in 10 to 15 lines. Why that will be too broad? But anyway, thanks you explicitly mentioned they are on topic.

Comment: @AmitJoshi I understand what you are saying but I think you did not understand what I said. The “unclear” reason isn’t used for just Qs which are unclear; SO merged several close reasons into that one reason a few years ago, and so now “unclear” is used more for “unclear **why** you’re asking”, aka “why do you need strangers on the internet to do your googling or your manual-reading tor you” aka “that’s answered in the documentation, to read that first and then come back to us with more specific Qs not answered by the documentation” aka “we are not a tutorial service” as Martin James put it.

Comment: 10-15 lines of insightful explanation, or 10-15 lines of text copied from the documentation/Google?

Comment: 10-15 lines of insightful explanation with links to section in documentation for supporting an answer AND good online resource/article available if any.

Comment: Myself, I would not bother either way with thoe examples - I'm not familiar with the protocols, so no action from me on tech. questions where I don't have tech, knowledge.

Comment: @AmitJoshi prolly. OK.  I would leave it to those with the relevant skillset.

Comment: @AmitJoshi This is the point. I have never heard of MLLP before never mind “enhanced mode”. I *literally* copied and pasted the words — your words — from example 3 into google, “What is enhanced mode in MLLP” and the very first hit was a precise explanation of exactly that topic: https://datica.com/academy/hl7-202-the-hl7-ack-acknowledgement-message/#enhanced-mode . Given that, it’s not clear why *you* didn’t do that, or what about that link or the 15 that followed it in Google didn’t help, and so your Qs will be closed as off-topic “we don’t do googling or read manuals for you” aka unclear.

Comment: @DanBron: **“why do you need strangers on the internet to do your googling or your manual-reading tor you”** I understand it now; thanks. But [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343853/5779732) answer says otherwise. All my examples fit the criteria (4 points) mentioned in that answer except third point. My examples do not contain code because those are purely for protocol.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question/10583#10583 `Too broad: The question must be edited to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer, and not ask multiple distinct questions at once.` There is no specific problem hence too broad.

Comment: @AmitJoshi This has nothing to do with code and everything to do with you doing your own basic legwork before asking experts on SO to volunteer their time to help you. It’s rude to ask someone else to do something you can easily do for yourself. On another site on the network, “English Language and Usage”, it is offtopic to ask “what does <word> mean”. Those questions are closed as “we are not an outsourced dictionary-reading service, go read the dictionary for yourself and come back with any remaining doubts”. It’s expected that you know that google and manuals exist & you use them b4 asking.

Comment: @AmitJoshi In other words,beginner questions are ok, but lazy questions are not. Here is a much more famous and much more upvoted Q&A than the one you linked:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. All questions **must show your own effort and research before asking** strangers on SO to volunteer their time to help you. This isn’t just an SO rule, it’s a **basic courtesy of human interaction**, and if you don’t follow it, **the rudeness will upset people** and furthermore **your questions will be closed**. Google, then ask

Comment: @DanBron: Ok; so those will be closed saying "unclear what you’re asking". Agreed. Does that mean they are still on-topic?

Comment: I thought that closable questions were by definition off-topic (with the exception of dupes). _"[Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: @yivi Not if you're consistent with your definitions, off-topic as defined by SO is only one of the close reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @Oleg, reading the linked page, I think it does say that the other close reasons also put the question in "off-topic" territory. That was my understanding anyway.

Comment: @AmitJoshi No, by definition, if they’re closed they’re off-topic. The whole point of making an argument that something is on-topic is *so it won’t be closed*. If it’s closed it can’t receive answers. The examples you’ve given will all be closed and will be barred from receiving answers. If you want them to remain open, try your hardest, on your own, before asking, to answer them for yourself. If you still can’t find the answer you need, write up the question, detail all the research you did, where you looked, what you found, what you didn’t find, and what *specific* doubts still remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clarification of protocols is on-topic. It can be DICOM, or OAuth, or any other protocol.

As developers, we have to deal with protocols. We find ourselves in situations where we need to understand them. Sometimes because we must implement them, sometimes because our software must use them. When you are struggling to understand a specific protocol, Stack Overflow is a fine place to find experts who can help you to understand it better.

Note that there can be some overlap with other sites. As was pointed out in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363269/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-a-question-about-protocol-irrespective-of-its-programming/363272#comment556932_363269), a question about TCP/IP might also be on-topic on Network Engineering Stack Exchange. A question about OAuth might also be on-topic on Information Security Stack Exchange.

As always, a question should show prior research effort. If the question can be answered with a quick search on Google, then the question does not belong on Stack Overflow.
But in general, a question about a well-known, public protocol is on-topic; it is the kind of knowledge that developers need.

Comment: Can you bold the first 2 sentences of your final paragraph? If so I could upvote you. I think that is the crux of the implied question here, though your answer appropriately responds to the explicit question.

Comment: @DanBron I dislike boldface, actually. The whole "prior research effort" thing has been discussed often enough. So, I'll just live without the upvote; but thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users#comment48318_261593) comment. What is bad 1) if next user tries to put research efforts (by googling) and the first result is a link from SO 2) if next user do not put research efforts at all and SO users close the question as "exact duplicate".